# Xamarin Firebase Authentication

Tags: xamarin, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

I am testing firebase authentication (and messaging). I am using:

Xamarin Firebase 32.4.0-beta2
Xamarin GooglePlayServices 32.4.0-beta2

When I call this:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(app);
```

I get this error:

> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafi$zza

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: That error message typically means that the device you're running on doesn't have (an up to date) version of Google Play Services installed.

Comment: Also remembering that it is not suported on Emulators

Comment: I used Xamarin.Firebase.Auth(60.1142.1) and Xamarin.Firebase.Core(60.1142.1) nugets without problems in my project.